# Refresh DNS in coldfusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, dns, jvm

Does anyone know of a way to flush the Cached DNS in the JVM in ColdFusion 9 without restarting the services.

Comment: I doubt it. As mentioned in the link below, caching is usually controlled by the security setting [`networkaddress.cache.ttl`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html). Changes to the value would require a jvm restart at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

You might try setting a custom value in the java.security file that would change the [TTL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) for the dns lookups, but I don't believe there is a programmatic way to clear the cache.

http://tjordahl.blogspot.com/2004/10/cfmx-and-dns-caching.html